# Postgres using debezium Creation of replication slot failed

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I configured debezium  with postgres as the below code, when i started my spring boot application a get an error `Creation of replication slot failed`

```
@Bean
public io.debezium.config.Configuration connector() {
    return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.CONNECTOR_CLASS, PostgresConnector.class)
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_STORAGE,  FileOffsetBackingStore.class)
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_STORAGE_FILE_FILENAME, "offset.dat")
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS, 60000)
            .with("name", "test-postgres-connector")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.SERVER_NAME, "172.26.113.123:5455-test")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.HOSTNAME, "172.26.113.123")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.PORT, "5455")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.USER, "test")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.PASSWORD, "test")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.DATABASE_NAME, "test")
            .with(RelationalDatabaseConnectorConfig.TABLE_INCLUDE_LIST, "question").build();
}


2021-04-02 12:58:56.817 ERROR 14672 --- [pool-5-thread-1] io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine      : Unable to initialize and start connector's task class 'io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask' with config: {name=student-postgres-connector, connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector, database.port=5455, offset.storage=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore, table.include.list=question, database.user=pfe, database.hostname=172.26.113.123, offset.storage.file.filename=offset.dat, database.password=********, offset.flush.interval.ms=60000, database.server.name=172.26.113.123:5455-pfe, database.dbname=pfe}

io.debezium.DebeziumException: Creation of replication slot failed
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:134) ~[debezium-connector-postgres-1.4.2.Final.jar:1.4.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:106) ~[debezium-core-1.4.2.Final.jar:1.4.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.embedded.EmbeddedEngine.run(EmbeddedEngine.java:758) ~[debezium-embedded-1.4.2.Final.jar:1.4.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: logical decoding requires wal_level >= logical
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.createReplicationSlot(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:352) ~[debezium-connector-postgres-1.4.2.Final.jar:1.4.2.Final]
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:127) ~[debezium-connector-postgres-1.4.2.Final.jar:1.4.2.Final]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you postgres instance uses a `wal_level` other than `logical`.

Debezium requires wal_level logical:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-wal.html

Take a look inside the postgres connector at the class:

`io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector.java`

Comment: Just to clarify: The wal_level is not set via Debezium, but must be configured for the database-server in postgres.conf (with restart). See https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-server-configuration

Comment: after setting wal_level=logical still same error for me